Install Gromacs/ gmx not found
I isntall gromacs with gpu cuda accelaration and after finished all process it worked and show but when i close the terminal and open new terminal and command any gmx work it show gmx not found / install sudo  apt gromacs. but in usr/local/gromacs all file ar there
. what gonna i do?

To make it persistent, you probably need to arrange to source the GMXRC file from your shell's initialization file (such as ~/.bashrc if you use bash) - see for example Getting access to GROMACS after installation
